# SWF Full screen error on Android ICS 4.0.3 - Tested on SGS2

Tags: android, webview, flash, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm developing an app that displays swf's inside a webview. My problem (**ICS 4.0.3 only**) , is that whenever I click the full screen button inside the swf the app displays a black screen for a couple of seconds and then crashes. I've tested the same code with lower api's (10) and it works fine.

**Facts:**
1- **ICS 4.0.3 - SWF in full screen inside webview crashes**.
2- **ICS 4.0.3 - SWF in full screen inside regular browser works.**

Is there any method in the **webview class** that allows me to fix this ? tks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a hack!

You need to do that :

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){ ... });
```